# How do I format code in comments?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting, markdown

I added a comment to the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591772/how-do-i-create-a-navigation-property-that-can-navigate-to-more-than-one-entity), I but couldn't get the code to format correctly. I made sure I was entering the four spaces.

The comment was only editable for 5 minutes, and it now appears too late to fix it. What should I do? The comment is important in explaining why I unaccepted the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 4-space indentation doesn't work in comments. Comments have a very dumbed down version of the full markdown that's available in posts.

The best you can do is put the ticks (``) around your code, using the key in the upper left near the numbers. This will highlight the code. You will not be able to do full indentation and stuff.

Comment: So here is a sentence. Here is `some code`. That's all you can do in a comment.

Comment: are the ticks(``) just a convention? They don't seem to reformat anything?
    "Here is my test tick"

Comment: Look closer. On some browsers on some monitors, it can be really hard to see. Compare "this" with "`this`". And make you use the correct tick. It's ` and not ' (the apostophe).

Comment: The difference is a lot more obvious on larger blocks of code: "if (x < 100) return 0; else return 1;" vs. "`if (x < 100) return 0; else return 1;`"

Comment: testing  Compare "this" vs ``this``  , The ticks are the same character aren't they?  how do you type them?

Comment: I think you're using the wrong tick. Use the one on the upper-left corner next to the numbers.

Comment: yes - i was using the wrong tick, and also didnt realise that the purpose of the tick was to create a highlight. I submitted an edit to your answer.